# Spyder (in Anacoda) stopped working offline once I upgraded to the new version (3.1.4.)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

i upgraded Spyder (in Anaconda) to 3.1.4.
it has now stopped showing up in the Anaconda menu when i logon while offline.
how can i fix this ? it used to work fine prior to my upgrade

Comment: can you still launch it, i.e. from the shell or bash ?

Comment: i can (not from Anaconda though)